# Como pegar o valor de vários itens e mudar segundo meu if

Tags: javascript, funções, for, binding, polymer

Tenho uma listagem de itens (que vem do banco de dados), preciso comparar cada item de um desses e se o valor for 0 mudar o texto.
Abaixo está a função que estou tentando usar para trocar o valor do item.

```
function isFree(){
    var preco = document.getElementsByClassName('comprar');
    for(n = 0; n < preco.length; n++){
      var validaPreco = preco[n].innerHTML;
      if(validaPreco == '$ 0'){
        validaPreco = 'Grátis'
      }
    }
  }
```

Quando utilizo a linha `document.getElementsByClassName('comprar')[0].innerHTML` no console do navegador tenho retornado o valor que quero usar para comparar, porém quero comparar todos os itens que são trazidos do banco.

E esta é a linha de código onde aparece o preço

```
<a href="detalhe/{{item.id}}" onclick="subir()"><button class="comprar">$ {{item.originalValue}}</button></a>
```

Só para deixar claro, estou usando polymer 2, o elemento firebase-query para trazer os dados.

Comment: Não dá pra ligar ao evento `change` das caixas de texto que atualizam esses `.comprar`? No caso, se for o caso, a quantidade? `<input type="text" id="qtd1"  ... onchange="isFree()" />`

Comment: Eu acho que tem um equívoco no seu código, na linha onde está `validaPreco = 'Grátis';` deveria ser `preco[n].innerHTML = 'Grátis';`

Comment: Objetos são passados por referência, em JS, enquanto que propriedades com tipos primitivos são passados por valor. Quando você fez `var validaPreco = preco[n].innerHTML`, você só conseguiu usar `preco[n]` como se fosse o próprio objeto que ele guarda porque é uma representação de passagem por referência. `preco[n].innerHTML`, por sua vez, tem tipo `String` e é passado por valor.

Comment: Pois é, realmente deveria trocar o validaPreco por preco[n]. Grato pela ajuda e pela explicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código:

```
function isFree(){
    var preco = document.getElementsByClassName('comprar');
    for(n = 0; n < preco.length; n++){
      var validaPreco = preco[n].innerHTML;
      if(validaPreco == '$ 0'){
        validaPreco = 'Grátis'
      }
    }
  }
```

Você define o valor de `validaPreco` como "Grátis", mas isso não irá se refletir no DOM, pois `validaPreco` e `preco[n].innerHTML` são objetos diferentes, mesmo que um seja cópia do outro. O que você precisa fazer é modificar o objeto no DOM:

```
function isFree(){
    var preco = document.getElementsByClassName('comprar');
    for(n = 0; n < preco.length; n++){
      var validaPreco = preco[n].innerHTML;
      if(validaPreco == '$ 0'){
        preco[n].innerHTML = 'Grátis'
      }
    }
  }
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
function isFree() {
  var preco = document.getElementsByClassName('comprar');
  for (n = 0; n < preco.length; n++) {
    var validaPreco = preco[n].innerHTML;
    if (validaPreco == '$ 0') {
      preco[n].innerHTML = 'Grátis'
    }
  }
}

isFree();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="comprar">$ 10,00</li>
  <li class="comprar">$ 0</li>
  <li class="comprar">$ 99,99</li>
  <li class="comprar">$ 0</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou. Era exatamente isso.